# JSON serialization with odd characters

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, model

There is an application that was originally written in Ruby on Rails that provides API services to several mobile applications; management has decided to add the functionality of the RoR service to the main .NET-based project.  OK, no big deal, we'll just duplicate the service calls in WebAPI right?  How difficult can it be?

Apparently somebody on the Ruby side thought it would be a swell idea to put extra characters into the api response objects.  I'm seeing things like:

```
{
    ...
    {"enabled?":true}
    ...
}
```

...so here I am, shaking my head at this, and hoping there is a technique to serialize .NET objects into JSON where variable names have question marks and whatnot.  Is there a way to do this, or are we going to have to build custom serializers for each of these objects?  Changing the mobile apps to consume more platform-friendly JSON is really not desirable at this point.  We use JSON.Net, but if there's another way to do this, it'd be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your c# object, give your property a [valid name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx) (such as `Enabled` in this case) and then specify the JSON property name in the [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of a [`DataMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, or the [`PropertyName`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_PropertyName.htm) property of a [`JsonProperty`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(Name="enabled?")]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("enabled?")]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

If you use `DataMemberAttribute`, don't forget to add the [`DataContract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, and that data contract serialization is [opt-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx), so you'll need to add `DataMember` to all the attributes you want to serialize.  Having done so, however, you'll gain compatibility with the [DataContractSerializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.xmlobjectserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which might be useful down the road.